# Ubuntu 12.04 installation freezes at 64%

Tags: 12.04, installation

I have now tried five times it install Ubuntu. Once in normal mode, three times in demo mode, and one in Safe graphic mode, but they all freeze at 64%.

Comment: were you connected to internet while installing?

Comment: Yeah, should I disconnect?

Comment: @kalebnoobmaster, yes, try installing with disconnected internet

Comment: It didn't work, still froze at 64%.

Comment: I get this error:  [483.460068] INFO jdb2/loop2-8:8665 blocked for more than 120 seconds. [483.460228] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.

Comment: Uhh.. I still need help anybody..,

Comment: test the CD for errors.  you may need to recreate the disk with a newly-downloaded ISO image.

Answer (score 3):

When you boot up, [select the option that checks the CD for errors](http://zootlinux.blogspot.com/2010/05/check-disc-for-defects-in-ubuntu-1004.html).